# How to get data from the velocity page in a action class?

Tags: java, struts2, velocity

How to get data from the velocity page in a action class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all HTML on the client side, and when user submit the HTML form, it work as simple as getting the parameters from the HttpServletRequest object. I hope you are getting my point.

So, don't confuse yourself with Velocity and stuff.